# Polynomial integral value at real point

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial with real coefficients. $deg(P) \ge 2$. Prove that it

is not possible that whenever $P(x)$ is an integer, $x$ is also an integer i.e., there exists

$x_0 \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$ such that $P(x_0)\in\mathbb{Z}$

I have no idea how to proceed!!!

Comment: Your question is not well asked.

Comment: Tell me what's the doubt?

Comment: I'm having computer problems. I can't write the rest of my answer . So I posted it to see if I could write it by editing it. No luck. So I deleted what I had  written so far.

Comment: Hint 1: $P(x+1)-P(x)$ is unbounded. Hint 2: The Intermediate Value Theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Gerry Myerson's hints.

Since $deg(P)\geq 2$, $P(x+1)-P(x)$ is a non constant polynomial, in particular unbounded as a function. Then, for large enough $c\in\mathbb{Z}$ we have $|P(c+1)-P(c)|>1$. Hence there is an integer $n$ such that $P(c)<n<P(c+1)$ or $P(c+1)<n<P(c)$.

In any case, P is continuous so by the intermediate value theorem there is $x_0\in \mathbb{R}$ with $c<x_0<c+1$ (hence $x_0\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$) such that $P(x_0)=n$.